# How do you write a for(i = 0; i < listName.length; i++) on Python?

Tags: python

When doing programming on Java or C++, I use this form of a *for* loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < listName.length; i++)
```

It was giving red squiggly lines, so I did some search online. From what it looks, there isn't any existence of this *for* loop method in Python. I am resorting to the 'for letter in listName' and *while* loops, but I have not been able to substitute the above *for* loop in Java or C++ successfully. I have included code that gets half of the expected outcome.

Code:

```
email = input("Please enter an email: ")

letterList = [*email]

for letter2 in letterList:
    if(letter2 == '.'):
        for letter3 in letterList:
            if(letter3 == '@'):
                for letterStop in letterList:

                        if letterStop == '.':
                            break
                        else:
                            print(letterStop)
```

This is the output of the above code when jason@gmail.com gets entered:

```
j
a
s
o
n
@
g
m
a
i
l
```

Input:

```
jason@gmail.com
```

Expected output:

```
gmail
```

Comment: ``for i in range(len(yourlist):`` is equivalent to ``for(i = 0; i < listName.length; i++)``

Comment: https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/

Comment: do you want to get the name between '@' and '.' ?

Comment: Python is not C.  If you do need the index (often, you don't) use `for index, letter in enumerate(email)`.  Note there is no need to convert `email` to a list.  Strings are iterable.

Comment: Try this - ```s.split('@')[1].split('.')[0]``` maybe?  -> ```gmail```

Comment: *) HamzaDevxx:  That was very helpful. Thanks man

      *)Mark Tolonen:  I did not know python had strings setup in such manner. Good seeing your post. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @DanielHao Nice spliting.

Comment: @HamzaDevXX - ```re``` should be the *way* to go... Thx.

Answer (score 1):

*For* loops exist in Python; they just have a different syntax.

```py
for i in range(len(my_string_or_list)):
    print(my_string_or_list[i])

for i,v in enumerate(my_string_or_list):
    print(f"Index {i} contains {v}")
```

You can use the `re` module (**re**gular expression) to extract the separate portions of an email address string into a list, and then get `gmail` from there:

```py
import re
re.split(r"[@.]", "jason@gmail.com")[1] # 'gmail'
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop you are talking about, **"for(i = 0; i < listName.length; i++)"**, exists in Python, but it's a bit different. And it would go like this: **"for i in range(len(yourlist):"**.

I see you are making a list out of string "letterList = [*email]", but you don't have to do that in Python. In Python, strings are iterable, so you can **"for i in email:"** and you would get every character.

The easiest way to get "gmail" out of the email address would be using the split() function like this.

```py
email = "jason@gmail.com"

a = email.split("@")[1]
b = a.split(".")[0]

print(b)
```

In a variable, we split the email in two strings, one before @ "jason" and one after "gmail.com". After that, we split "gmail.com" into two strings.